# StackOverflowException was unhandled when trying to count how many pages are in a PDF

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, pdf, stack-overflow

I have an application that runs from a batch file using parameters in said file to pull PDF email attachments from an email inbox. It takes those and saves them onto drive so our web app can display them to a user. Essentially it is an incoming email handler.

Anyway, I am getting this error:

> System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
>
> {Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack
>   overflow state.}

Here is the code:

```
static List<string> SplitPDF(string PDFPath)
{
   try
   {
      List<string> retval = new List<string>();
      ExpertPdf.PDFSplit.PDFSplitManager pds = new PDFSplitManager();
      pds.LicenseKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
      int Pages = pds.GetPdfPageCount(PDFPath);

      for (int i = 0; i < Pages; i++)
      {
         pds.ExtractPagesFromFileToFile(PDFPath, PDFPath + i.ToString() + ".pdf", i + 1, 1);
         retval.Add(PDFPath + i.ToString() + ".pdf");
      }
      retval.Add(PDFPath);

     return retval;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      throw ex;
   }
}
```

This method throws the error on

```
int Pages = pds.GetPdfPageCount(PDFPath);
```

Don't know why or how. The funny thing is, it only happens with one of three batch files. The other two work fine (Production fails, dev and test work fine).

We think it may have to do with the file folders, maybe something is happening in there, but I am unsure...

Any suggestions? Need any other code? I know I only provided one method, but that is where the error is.

Thanks!

EDIT: here is the stack trace, if it helps

> IncomingFax.exe!IncomingFax.Program.SplitPDF(string PDFPath = "D:\www\443\PBIN\fax\inbox\preproc\3lz3npbd2sy") Line 726 + 0x17 bytes

```
IncomingFax.exe!IncomingFax.Program.ProcessMessage(ForAspNet.POP3.EmailMessage Message = {ForAspNet.POP3.EmailMessage}) Line 326 + 0x9 bytes        

IncomingFax.exe!IncomingFax.Program.Main(string[] args = {string[6]}) Line 78 + 0x9 bytes
```

Comment: what does `PDFPath` look like ?

Comment: @Tigran D:\www\443\PBIN\fax\inbox

in code it's D:\\www\\443\\PBIN\\fax\\inbox

Comment: does it only happen with specific PDF files? What happens if you pull the PDF file that it failed on and throw it in your test system? Does it crash too? If it happens after multiple PDF files have been processed and it's not reproducable with files that it crashed on before: Monitor the RAM usage of your program. Does PDFSplitManager have a .Dispose() method? If yes, call it!

Comment: That PDF does crash my test system as well, and no, there is no Dispose() method on PdfSplitManager. Checking ram now.

Comment: @Steffen my physical memory and CPU usage jump to about 40-60% when I run the app

Comment: well, take a look at if the RAM is free'd after a PDF was processed or if it keeps increasing everytime you get a new PDF.

As for the crashing: Maybe you should get something to analyze the PDF so that you can compare it to a 'working' PDF. Is the page count greater than for 'working' PDF files?

You could also try to throw in a working PDF again and again [shouldn't be a problem on your test system], just to be sure that it's not RAM related.

Comment: what is the implementation of `PDFSplitManager.GetPDFPageCount(string PDFPath)`?

Comment: @WillFaithfull what exactly do you mean? It is used to count the number of pages in a pdf document.

Comment: @Steffen the bad document was significantly larger (about twice the size) of a good document. The good document's threw another exception, but that's a different issue that is completely unrelated.

Comment: I mean, is there some kind of recursion in that method which is causing a stack overflow? You mention that the method throws the exception on this line `int Pages = pds.GetPdfPageCount(PDFPath);`

Comment: @WillFaithfull There is no recursion as far as I know, but the method is from a third part dll so there very well could be. It says it's from mscorlib.dll if that helps?

Comment: @Carson did you try to contact the company for support?

Comment: @SteffenWinkler not yet, but I may have to.

Comment: Interesting. It sounds to me like there may be a bug in the [third party dll](http://www.html-to-pdf.net/docs/split-pdf-library/html/55766c1c-961d-e47d-ff06-00fad70c260f.htm) (is this the right one?) which is causing the stack overflow.

Comment: @Steffen it seems it is only on one specific PDF now... for some reason this specific PDF isn't kosher, but others are. I think it is because it is scaned in and not system generated, but I'm not sure. Even so, that is an issue.

Comment: @WillFaithful it seems so.

Comment: @Carson well, you could try to throw an equally large PDF in there on your test system. If you don't have one, use a PDF merger to create one. (personally I prefer PDF-Shuffler, though I do not know if it exists for Windows)

You could also try to create a similiar PDF without 'secrets' using the same method with which the failing PDF was created. Test it, if it crashes your program, send it over to them.

Comment: Can you provide the non-kosher PDF for inspection?

Comment: @mkl I would rather not. There is sensative information on it.

Comment: In that case I would advice you to take some PDF interna browser (e.g. RUPS) and with it inspect the page tree of your document having the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) open on your second screen. A stack overflow in `GetPdfPageCount` seems to point in that direction...